# Migration Script: replacing ' in data with ''

Tags: sql, sql-server, scripting, varchar

I apologize if this has been answered but I could not find it while searching.

I'm writing a stored procedure which generates a migration script and have something in it like this:

```
'insert into dbo.source_line_items (id, name, comment) 
                                    VALUES('
                                    + ' '+ CASE WHEN  id IS NULL THEN isnull(id,'NULL') ELSE ''''+ id   + '''' END + ', '
+ ' '+ CASE WHEN  name IS NULL THEN isnull(name,'NULL') ELSE ''''+ name   + '''' END + ', '
+ ' '+ CASE WHEN  comment IS NULL THEN isnull(comment,'NULL') ELSE ''''+ comment   + '''' END + ', '
```

This is working in general, but some of the data I am migrating has the character' in it.   Therefore, I generate a few sql statements like

```
insert into Table(id, name, comment) 
                                    VALUES('874', 'O'Brien',NULL)
```

Is there an easy way to have my script automatically replace the ' with '' when the ' is in the data?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server uses double ticks to find single ticks within a string.  Use `REPLACE()` with double ticks like so:

```
REPLACE(name,'''','') --To remove ticks
REPLACE(name,'''','''''') --To replace single with double ticks
```

In full:

```
CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN isnull(name,'NULL') 
ELSE ''''+ REPLACE(name,'''','''''') + '''' END
```